# Create an org-agenda-custom-commands using org-agenda-filter

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Org-mode newbie here.

I use the `org-agenda-filter` pretty heavily as part of my daily agenda workflow. I have a tag for "Work" related TODO items and repeat this operation several times a day:

1. Pressing C-a a
2. invoke the org-agenda-filter using `/`
3. filter to my tag and TODO items of interest e.g. Work/TODO

I want to create a custom filter command for this and have worked on this so far:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("w" "List Work Tasks"
 ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-span 'week)))
  (org-agenda-filter '("Work/TODO"))))))
```

When I press C-a w, it asks me to enter my Tag/TODO keywords again. It seems like this code is not able to pass the search terms to org-agenda filter.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In step 1, I don't know what `C-a a` does. Can you clarify? Do you mean `C-c a` as described in [Activation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Activation.html) in the manual? If you really mean `C-a a`, then tell us what that is bound to: do `C-h c C-a a` and tell us what it says. Then in step 2, what does '/' do? In my agenda dispatcher, it does `Multi-occur` which is a text search function, not a tag/TODO search. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This seems surprisingly hard to do! The recommended approach seems to be [this footnote in the docs](https://orgmode.org/manual/Filtering_002flimiting-agenda-items.html#FOOT97). It describes creating custom agenda commands where:

> ...  one of the variables `org-agenda-tag-filter-preset`, `org-agenda-category-filter-preset`, `org-agenda-effort-filter-preset` or `org-agenda-regexp-filter-preset` [are set] as an option. This filter is then applied to the view and persists as a basic filter through refreshes and more secondary filtering.

Like you, I didn't really want a dedicated org-agenda command, instead to bind to a key for turning on and off a particular filter inside any agenda. In my case, I wanted to toggle a category filter not a tag.

None of the "interactive" org-agenda filter functions support passing in the filter value as an argument, they all either prompt or take the filter value from under the point.

I went looking at the function implementations. `org-agenda-filter-by-category` is less general than `org-agenda-filter`, so it was a bit easier to understand. This function updates the variable `org-agenda-category-filter` and then calls `org-agenda-filter-apply` with the result. Here's the key bit:

```lisp
(org-agenda-filter-apply
 (setq org-agenda-category-filter
  (list (concat "+" cat)))
 'category)
```

On that basis, I wrote a function similar to this:

```lisp
(defun my/org-agenda-toggle-work ()
 "Toggle excluding work category from the agenda"
 (interactive)
 (if org-agenda-category-filter
  (org-agenda-remove-filter 'category)
  (org-agenda-filter-apply (setq org-agenda-category-filter '("-work")) 'category)
  ))
```

And bound it to a key in `org-agenda-mode-map`. Seems to work!

I think you could do the same thing for a tag filter, but instead set variable `org-agenda-tag-filter` and pass `'tag` as the type.

Overall this seems like an ugly hack that couples too deeply into the implementation of `org-agenda` filtering. Would like to find a nicer way to do this (for example, extending the interactive function `org-agenda-filter` to take an optional value argument).